# WSO2 ESB - HL7 console - JPAStore configuration with MS SQL and cast of PersistenceCapable failed

Tags: sql-server, jpa, wso2-esb

I'm trying to configure a messageStore for HL7 following the [documentations](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/HL7+Transport)
 (with both **WSO2 ESB 5.0.0** and **EI 6.0.0**) In my case the difference is to use MS SQL instead of MySql.
My target is store the hl7 messages and using the hl7 console for audit.

My problem is that WSO2 fails to save the messages in the messageStore with the following errors:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-04-06 09:34:04,189] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.business.messaging.hl7.store.jpa.JPAProducer} -  Could not store HL7 message. Attempt to cast instance "org.wso2.carbon.business.messaging.hl7.store.entity.PersistentHL7Message@7ddb9a02" to PersistenceCapable failed. The object implemented org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PersistenceCapable, but the instance of that interface was loaded by two different ClassLoaders: "org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@3f9e5e46[openjpa-all:2.2.2.wso2v1(id=131)]" and "org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@45563386[tomee:1.7.2.wso2v2(id=634)]". {org.wso2.carbon.business.messaging.hl7.store.jpa.JPAProducer}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-04-06 09:34:04,192] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.store.MessageStoreMediator} -  Failed to store message [urn:uuid:E27D55866515A24A371491464043938] in store [HL7StoreJPA]. {org.apache.synapse.mediators.store.MessageStoreMediator}
```

This is the messageStore

```
<messageStore class="org.wso2.carbon.business.messaging.hl7.store.jpa.JPAStore" name="HL7StoreJPA" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName">org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource</parameter>
    <parameter name="openjpa.ConnectionProperties">DriverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver, Url=jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS, DatabaseName=HL7StoreJPA,  MaxActive=100,  MaxWait=10000,  TestOnBorrow=true,  Username=hl7Store,  Password=hl7Store</parameter>
    <parameter name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary">sqlserver(blobTypeName=varbinary)</parameter>
</messageStore>
```

This is the proxy:

```
<proxy name="Hl7OnlyStoreProxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="hl7" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="HL7_RESULT_MODE" value="ACK" scope="axis2"/>
            <log level="full"/>
            <property name="messageType" value="application/edi-hl7" scope="axis2"/>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <store messageStore="HL7StoreJPA"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.hl7.AutoAck">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.hl7.Port">9296</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.hl7.ValidateMessage">false</parameter>
</proxy>
```

The HL7 Console
[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I have replaced MS SQL with Oracle Database XE 11.2 and after the creation manually of the table PERSISTENTHL7STORE the HL7 console work good with WSO2 EI 6.1.0 !